# Dynamically Add Lines to UILabel in Swift

Tags: iphone, swift, ios8, uilabel

I have a basic UIViewController with a UILabel that I want to populate dynamically at runtime. I want the elements surrounding the UILabel to move as the UILabel expands. I have constraints added that should allow for this, but I haven't been able to test it because my lines don't wrap on the Label like they should. I have set the Number of Lines in the Attributes Inspector to 0 and changed the Line Break mode to Word Wrap. However, the UILabel box won't expand in height to account for the amount of text. How can I go about setting this up? Thank you!!

[image: This is the UILabel I'm trying to adjust dynamically.]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Constraints are not created right.

I would suggest you create a new project and start with two labels to get a better understanding of how `autolayout` works.

Try deleting your `Height-Constraint`. 
`Autolayout` will think that it needs to maintain the Height of 21 in your case. 
If you delete it or set it with a low priority it should work.

*I recreated your sample and got it working:*

[image: The TopLabel (With the Big Text]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You are right. I need to learn how to better control my use of constraints. I typically use the iOS suggested constraints. Thank you for you help!!